# C int array shrinking when passed

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am passing an array of `int` with 4 elements into a function and `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is saying I have fewer elements.

Here's example of what's happening:

```
int
main() {
  // declaring literal array
  int array[] = {1,2,3,5};

  // prints 16/4 (correct output for 4 elements)
  printf("%d/%d\n", sizeof(array), sizeof(array[0]));

  function(array);

  return 0;
}

void
function(int array[]) {
  // printing 8/4 instead of 16/4
  printf("%d/%d\n", sizeof(array), sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

Comment: With all the edits, I wanna know (a) what happened to the *original* question, and (b) where is `matrix_transposition_key` declared?? The original question used `array[]` in the printf in `function()` this does not, and no longer even compiles.

Comment: You can't pass arrays to functions or return them from functions; they degrade to pointers to their first element.

Comment: Sorry was rewriting some code to be generalized and copy/pasted the printf statements.  I'll edit to fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that function arguments that are arrays are transformed into pointers by the compiler. So it is as if your function had the signature

```
void function(int *array);
```

This means two things:

1. You have to pass the size of the array explicitly as another parameter, since it has been "lost".
2. `sizeof(array)` will only tell you what the size of a pointer is in your architecture. So by your output, we can tell that you are compiling for a 64-bit target but nothing else.

Note that `sizeof(array[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(*array)` (pointer arithmetic), so it will still give the correct value no matter what.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass the size as a parameter.

Comment: Also note, while this is very likely the problem, the posted code isn't using the parameter in its `printf()` anyway; its using the same unknown global that was used in `main()`. Now that *would* be a mystery if they printed different results.

Answer (score 1):

The sizeof inside the function returns the sizeof pointer to your array which can is 4 or 8 depending on your system.

Comment: Or 2, if you're on a 16-bit system :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass array as an I/P argument to a function, it is treated as a pointer containing its base address.

You are getting: sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(first element of array)

In GDB: (inside function() )

```
(gdb) pt matrix_transposition_key                                                               
type = int *                                                                                    
(gdb) pt matrix_transposition_key[0]                                                 
type = int 

(gdb) p sizeof(matrix_transposition_key)
$2 = 8                                                                                          
(gdb) p sizeof(matrix_transposition_key[0])                                                       
$3 = 4
```